# Difference between 50% and 70px border-radius for a 140px width element in CSS

Tags: html, css, math, frontend

I have encountered a peculiar visual difference when setting the border-radius property in CSS. In CSS battle first challenge target #8, I have a  element with a fixed width of 140px. The border-bottom-left-radius is set to 50%, while the border-bottom-right-radius is set to 70px. Logically, 50% should be equal to 70px in this case since the width of the element is known. However, when rendered, there is a small distinction between the two corner radii, I want to know why this happen.
this is the code you can put it in: " https://cssbattle.dev/play/8 "**turn on Diff to check the difference**.

```css
<div a></div>
    <style>
      div {
        position:fixed;
        left:130px;
        width: 140px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius:70px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #dd6b4d;
       }
      div[a]{
        top:100px;  
      }
```

I have tried asking ChatGPT, and it suggested that the issue might be due to browser rendering. However, I tested it on both Chrome and Bing browsers and encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Logically, 50% should be equal to 70px in this case since the width of the element is known.

Your mistake here is in assuming that this was dependent only on the width - but it isn't.

With `border-bottom-left-radius` (and the others as well), you are actually specifying *two* radiuses, one for the semi-major and one for the semi-minor axes of the ellipse.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius#values:

> Percentages for the horizontal axis refer to the width of the box, percentages for the vertical axis refer to the height of the box.

You specified only one value here, `50%` - so you are setting a border radius of 50% of the width in one of the axis directions, and 50% of the height in the other.

Your element is 140px wide, and 150px high. And 50% of 140, are a different value than 50% of 150.

So of course you get a different curve here, than you would with `70px` - with that, you are setting the *same* radius for both axes.